# Find the volumes.

Tags: calculus

I need volumes of the solid, bounded by the surfaces:
 $x^2 + y^2 = a^2, z = 0, x + y + z = 4a$.
 I want to use polar coordinates and then integrate it but cannot get the domain of integration. The first idea was to say that $y=0$ and draw a plot, however, it's not symmetric, thus I don't know the radius. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an error in your problem. If you graph $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x+y=4a$ they never intersect except for $0$.

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = a^2$ is a circle of radius $a$ in the x-y plane, $z=0$ is the x-y plane, and $x+y+z=4a$ is a plane above the x-y plane. Try reformulating the bounds as cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ to get the domain of integration.

Comment: Well, I could say that $x = r\cos{\theta}$ and  $y = r\sin{\theta}$, but still there is a problem with radius...